# Isotope.js not filtering correctly when using multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have a simple filter which contains two `checkboxes`, one for `cake` another for `cupcake`.

A user can check either option, or select both to show all results. However, even though my `filters` array contains the correct values, nothing shows.

Even when filtering by one option, it doesn't showcase the correct results.

See demo here:

```js
(function($) {

  var $grid = $('.shop__grid'),
    $checkboxes = $('.isotope-trigger');

  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.productCard',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });

  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
    $grid.isotope('layout');
  });


  $checkboxes.change(function() {
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
      filters.push(this.value);
    });
    // filters = filters.join(', ');
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: filters
    });
    console.log(filters);
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@5/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="shop">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- filter -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="shopFilter">
          <div class="shopFilter__category">
            <span class="shopFilter__category-label d-block">Type</span>
            <div class="shopFilter__category-options">
              <div class="filterOption">
                <input class="filterOption__input isotope-trigger" type="checkbox" data-filter=".cake" name="item-cake" value="Cake" id="cake">
                <label class="filterOption__label" for="item-cake">Cake</label>
              </div>
              <div class="filterOption">
                <input class="filterOption__input isotope-trigger" type="checkbox" data-filter=".cupcake" name="item-cupcake" value="Cupcake" id="cupcake">
                <label class="filterOption__label" for="item-cupcake">Cupcake</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- listing -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
        <div class="shop__grid">
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cupcake">Cupcake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed 2 things:

1. you transferred the values instead of the id's
2. the ids of the checkboxes serve as classnames for $grid, so they have to be prepended with a dot.

My changes can be reduced to these lines, the rest is there to demonstrate that it's running:

```
$checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
  filters.push(this.id);
});

var filtersString = filters.length > 0 ? '.' + filters.join(', .') : '';

// console.log(filtersString);

$grid.isotope({
  filter: filtersString
});
```

Demonstration:

```js
(function($) {

  var $grid = $('.shop__grid'),
    $checkboxes = $('.isotope-trigger');

  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.productCard',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });

  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
    $grid.isotope('layout');
  });


  $checkboxes.change(function() {
var filters = [];
// get checked checkboxes values
$checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
  filters.push(this.id);
});

var filtersString = filters.length > 0 ? '.' + filters.join(', .') : '';

console.log(filtersString);

$grid.isotope({
  filter: filtersString
});

// console.log(filters);
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@5/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="shop">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- filter -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="shopFilter">
          <div class="shopFilter__category">
            <span class="shopFilter__category-label d-block">Type</span>
            <div class="shopFilter__category-options">
              <div class="filterOption">
                <input class="filterOption__input isotope-trigger" type="checkbox" data-filter=".cake" name="item-cake" value="Cake" id="cake">
                <label class="filterOption__label" for="item-cake">Cake</label>
              </div>
              <div class="filterOption">
                <input class="filterOption__input isotope-trigger" type="checkbox" data-filter=".cupcake" name="item-cupcake" value="Cupcake" id="cupcake">
                <label class="filterOption__label" for="item-cupcake">Cupcake</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- listing -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
        <div class="shop__grid">
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cupcake">Cupcake</div>
          <div class="productCard text-center cake">Cake</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I found a documentation about the filter: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html